# UITableView cell getting sent setSelected:NO during layoutView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I am seeing some weird things happening with viewDidLayoutSubviews and UITableViewCells.

I have 2 tables on a page, both of which get sized so they do not scroll (all elements are visible). I take care of the resizing in viewDidLayoutSubviews like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    self.orderItemTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.orderItemTableView.contentSize.height - [self tableView:self.orderItemTableView heightForHeaderInSection:0];
    self.shippingOptionTableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.shippingMethodTableView.contentSize.height;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    self.scrollViewContainerViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.shippingMethodTableView.$bottom;

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

This works as expected.

However, when shippingOptionTableView is built, it has 3 cells (for this example), each with a model that feeds the label in the cell and a selection marker like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == self.shippingMethodTableView) {
        DLShippingOptionTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SHIPPING_OPTION_CELL_IDENTIFIER];

        if (cell == nil) {
            NSString *nibName = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) ? @"DLShippingOptionTableCell~iphone" : @"DLShippingOptionTableCell";

            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:nil options:nil];

            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[DLShippingOptionTableCell class]]) {
                    cell = (DLShippingOptionTableCell *)currentObject;
                    [cell setupCell];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        cell.model = [self.model.shippingOptionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

The model gets set in the table cell, which causes the visual state to be updated:

```
- (void)setModel:(DLShippingOption *)model {
    _model = model;

    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

    NSString *numberAsString = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(model.priceInPennies / 100.0f)]];

    self.shippingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", model.optionName, numberAsString];

    [self toggleSelectedState:model.isSelected];
}

- (void)toggleSelectedState:(BOOL)isSelected {
    [self setSelected:isSelected];

    self.radioButtonImageView.image = isSelected ? [UIImage imageNamed: @"radio_button_selected.jpg"] : [UIImage imageNamed: @"radio_button_unselected.jpg"];
}
```

Here is the problem... the table cell get sent setSelected:NO repeatedly during the layout process.  So, even when my model is set to selected, and I update the radio-button graphic (which I would normally do in setModel:) it gets overridden and changed to false.

I had to put this hack in place to make it work (basically adding this bit of code to the cellForRowAtIndexPath in the ViewController, just after setting the cell's model:

```
if (cell.model.isSelected) {
    [self.shippingMethodTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
}
```

I this bites... So the question is, why are table cells getting sent setSelected:NO over and over and over during layout, and is there a better way to overcome that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **prepareForReuse** method and see if it helps. It will be also helpful to see the documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

*If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. **For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state**. The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass implementation.*

Also note that you should only use this method for stuff which is **not** related to content as pointed out in the documentation. Content related stuff should always be done in *tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:* method